# does "yet to come" mean "after" or "later" or "in future"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Battles between British troops and colonial
militiamen in Lexington and Concord in April 1775
kicked off the armed conflict, and by the following
summer, the rebels were conducting a full-scale war
for their independence.
Yet to come were the Patriot triumphs
at Saratoga, or the bitter winter at Valley Forge.

Comment: In the example "Yet to come" means in the future of the time spoken of, i.e. in the future of these events which happened in the past.  "After" would not work here at all.

Comment: The sentence is reordered from the usual "the Patriot triumphs at Saratoga were yet to come", if that's your problem. This is common in literary writing, done to provide a contrast. "To come" means in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> Yet to come were the Patriot triumphs at Saratoga, or the bitter winter at Valley Forge.

If I was going to give an equivalent I would write

> Still in the future were the Patriot triumphs at Saratoga, or the bitter winter at Valley Forge.

Of the other options you give *after* seems to me definitely not good, *later* would work but is not quite such a close equivalent.